# Error Installing CyberPanel on Ubuntu 18.04 (Oops, something went wrong...)

Tags: 18.04, dependencies, pure-ftpd

My name is Samuel, I am not so new to Linux OS though, but I encountered this error while trying to install Cyberpanel using the official instruction on the Cyperpanel website.

I got the message

```
Oops, something went wrong...
```

and the installation was not completed, so I looked for the log and I found the last two lines saying something about

```
We are not able to run apt-get -y install pure-ftpd return code: 100.
```

So I tried running `apt-get -y install pure-ftpd` manually, and I got an error about a dependency not met see the message. I got:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pure-ftpd : Depends: pure-ftpd-common (= 1.0.46-1build1) but 1.0.47-3 is to be installed
```

My guess is that Cyberpanel installation failed because of the dependency issue.

Anyone please kindly help resolve this.

Comment: If you look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=pure-ftpd-common you'll note the 1.0.45 is the version Ubuntu bionic ships with, so you possibly have a source added in your machine that is the problem. I'd suggest `apt-cache policy pure-ftpd-common` to see where you system has been told to get it's packages from to detect your issue.

Comment: What OS/release are you using?  You're trying to install the 19.04/disco package, so are you really running Ubuntu 18.04/bionic?   Why do you have 19.04/disco sources on your system?   I would suggest running `ubuntu-support-status` on your system if it's connected to the internet, as your system maybe rather insecure...

Comment: Thank you for the response @guiverc. running `apt-cache policy pure-ftpd-common` returned 
`pure-ftpd-common:
  Installed: 1.0.47-3
  Candidate: 1.0.47-3
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.47-3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.46-1build1 500
        500 http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages`

looking at the above is the source not correct?

Comment: Running `apt-cache policy pure-ftpd-common --show-unsupported`

Comment: `Support status summary of 'previesam-HP-ProBook-6550b':

You have 1898 packages (84.7%) supported until April 2023 (Canonical - 5y)
You have 121 packages (5.4%) supported until April 2021 (Community - 3y)
You have 2 packages (0.1%) supported until April 2021 (Canonical - 3y)

You have 6 packages (0.3%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 215 packages (9.6%) that are unsupported

Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2023.

No longer downloadable:
lutris playonlinux pure-ftpd-common pure-ftpd-mysql uget wps-office `

Comment: Please don't add additional information to comments, if you reply with extra (requested or not) detail please add to your question where it can be formatted & edited.